# The find() function from std::map returns a value despite not having a valid key

Tags: c++, enums, hashtable, stdmap, std-pair

**Background:**
I wanted to create a state-diagram using `std::pair` and `std::map`.

**Documentation says:**

According to the documentation for [map::find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find), we know:

> Return value
>
> Iterator to an element with key equivalent to key. If no such element
>   is found, past-the-end (see end()) iterator is returned.

**Idea/Logic**:

I had this simple program:

- with two `enums` -

  - one for the states and,
  - one for the transitions,
- used together with the `map`.
- The `key` in the `map` is a `std::pair`.  The `pair` consists of an initial state and a transition.
- With `find` applied on the above `key`, we can get the next state.

**Code**:

Here is the code:

```
#include <utility>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

typedef enum {
    State_Undefined = 0,
    State_NotConnected = 1,
    State_Transporting = 2,
    State_TransportFinished = 3,
    State_TransportStopped = 4
} State;
typedef enum {
    Transition_Undefined = 0,
    Transition_StopTransport = 1,
    Transition_StartTransport = 2,
    Transition_FinishTransport = 3
} Transition;

typedef std::pair<const State, const Transition> InitStateAndTransition;
typedef std::map<InitStateAndTransition, State> NextStateFromCurrentStateAndTransition;

NextStateFromCurrentStateAndTransition myMap = {
    {{State_NotConnected, Transition_StartTransport}, State_Transporting},
    {{State_Transporting, Transition_StopTransport}, State_TransportStopped},
    {{State_TransportStopped, Transition_FinishTransport}, State_TransportFinished},
    {{State_TransportStopped, Transition_StartTransport}, State_Transporting}
};

int main()
{
    State currentState = State_NotConnected;

    Transition testInput = Transition_StartTransport;
    State nextState = myMap.find(InitStateAndTransition(currentState, testInput))->second;
    std::cout << nextState << std::endl;

    testInput= Transition_StartTransport;
    nextState = myMap.find(InitStateAndTransition(nextState, testInput))->second;
    std::cout << nextState << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Surprisingly, this returns the output,

> 2
>
> 0

The `0` represents the `State_Undefined`, I guess. This is surprising. I had expected an error or a warning, since there is no State_Undefined in the hash table, I initialized.

**Note:**

I understand, I should check the iterator in `main()` function like this, and then this situation can be avoided.

```
    if (myMap.end() == myMap.find(InitStateAndTransition(nextState, testInput))) {
        return -1;
    }
```

**Question**:

But, I just can not understand, how or why the `find()->second` can return a `0` a.k.a the enum `State_Undefined`. I never put that value in the hash table.

Comment: That's because `find()->second` used with the `end()` iterator as result is _undefined behavior_.

Comment: I learned something new today. I was looking into the documentation for `map::find`. Apparently, I should've looked into **iterators**. Thanks guys.

Comment: @RaymondChen, yes. He had the same underlying problem as me, but his problem-statement is totally different. Like I said, I was not thinking about **iterators**. I was thinking why **find** is working weirdly here.

Comment: The documentation you quoted says that `find` returns an iterator, and in the case where the item is not found, it returns a "past-the-end iterator". That should have been your clue that what you had was an iterator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is that you are not checking the result of `find`. If the returned iterator is equal to `end()`, then dereferencing it is undefined behavior.

In this case, it just randomly returned 0. It could have been -1. Or a crash. Or anything else.

Answer (score 2):

> This is surprising. I had expected an error or a warning, since there is no State_Undefined in the hash table, I initialized.

The behaviour of indirecting past-the-end iterator is undefined. It would be misguided to expect some particular behaviour.

> But, I just can not understand, how or why the find()->second can return a 0 a.k.a the enum State_Undefined. I never put that value in the hash table.

The behaviour is undefined. Anything can happen.

---

If you want to have an exception when the element does not exist, you can use `map::at` instead of `map::find`.

Comment: thanks for the `map::at` tip. I didn't know about it.